# C# Access textbox from a class?

Tags: c#

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{


    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Authenticator at = new Authenticator();
            at.validate();
        }
    }

    public class Authenticator
    {
        private int num;

        public bool validate()
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == num.ToString()) // problem #1
            {
                 ListBox.Items.Add("Valid"); // problem #2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hello everyone.

As you can see from the above code I am writing an application that requires a user defined class to be able to access the winforms I am working with like in the above simplified example. I'm very new to C# so please forgive my ignorance.

I need the authenticator class to be able to access the data in a textbox and then compare it and if both strings are equal then update the listbox. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Probably best to keep the gui separate from the logic:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Authenticator at = new Authenticator();
        if (at.validate(textBox1.Text)) {
            ListBox.Items.Add("Valid");
        }
    }
}

public class Authenticator
{
    private int num;

    public bool validate(string s)
    {
        if (s == num.ToString())
        {
             return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this?

```
public bool validate(string text)
{
     return (text == num.ToString());
}
```

And calling it in your code like this. You should try to make code as reusable as possible. Which means that references to specific instances of controls on a Form is not always the best design.

```
if (at.validate(textBox1.Text))
{
     ListBox.Items.Add("Valid");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't comment on your post, I don't have enough reputation.

I've had similar trouble once before getting a form to access a string from another form.

In my case I just had to make the string static. Try doing the same with your textbox.

```
public static TextBox textBox1;
public Form1()
```